# Change url to posts if they have custom tax only

Tags: filters, url-rewriting, urls, rewrite-rules

I have custom taxonomy "category_slider".

```
function taxonomy_slider() {
$labels = array(
    'name'              => 'Категории проекта',
    'singular_name'     => 'Категории',
    'search_items'      => 'Поиск Категорий',
    'all_items'         => 'Все Категории',
    'parent_item'       => 'Родительская Категория',
    'parent_item_colon' => 'Родительская Категория:',
    'edit_item'         => 'Редактировать Категорию',
    'update_item'       => 'Обновить Категорию',
    'add_new_item'      => 'Добавить Категорию',
    'new_item_name'     => 'Название Категории',
    'menu_name'         => 'Категории проекта',
);

$args = array(
    'labels' => $labels,
    'hierarchical' => true,
    'query_var' => 'category_slider',
    'rewrite' => true,
    'show_admin_column' => true,
);
register_taxonomy( 'category_slider', 'attachment', $args );
}
add_action( 'init', 'taxonomy_slider');
```

How can i change my permalink structure "site.com/post/post_data/post_name/" only for posts who has tax "taxonomy_slider" to "site.com/category_slider_name/post_data/post_name/" ?

Answer (score 0):

It works for me.

```
add_filter('post_link', 'locale_permalink', 10, 3);
add_filter('post_type_link', 'locale_permalink', 10, 3);

function locale_permalink($permalink, $post_id, $leavename) {
    if (strpos($permalink, '%category_slider%') === FALSE) return $permalink;

$post = get_post($post_id);
if (!$post) return $permalink;
    if ($post->post_type != 'post') {
        return $permalink;
    } else {
        $terms = wp_get_object_terms($post->ID, 'category_slider');
        if (!is_wp_error($terms) && !empty($terms) && is_object($terms[0])) $taxonomy_slug = $terms[0]->slug;
        else $taxonomy_slug = 'news';
        return str_replace('%category_slider%', $taxonomy_slug, $permalink);
    }
}

add_filter('rewrite_rules_array','remove_bare_folder_rule');
function remove_bare_folder_rule( $rules )
{
    unset($rules['([^/]+)/?$']);
    return $rules;
}
```